# Slow Consumers on Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, python-multiprocessing, kafka-consumer-api

I use Kafka to maintain a Python service which should be working on parallel to handle the slow API requests for each message efficiently.

I used multiprocessing module on Python and kafka-python for the consumers.

ZooKeeper and Kafka 2.11 runs on the same Ubuntu server with mostly defult configurations.

The topic is auto-created with another kafka-python producer and set to have 10 partitions in order to use up to 10 consumers at the same time.

When I check, I see that the queue is really long, so the producer sends so many requests:

```
$ bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic usrReq --time -1
usrReq:8:1157
usrReq:2:1185
usrReq:5:1167
usrReq:4:1115
usrReq:7:1164
usrReq:10:1150
usrReq:1:1149
usrReq:9:1138
usrReq:3:1186
usrReq:6:1220
usrReq:0:6264
```

However; although working 10 cores in parallel, consumers take very long time (117 seconds on a sample log below) to get the next message from the queue.

```
thread 7, consumer: 117.485 sec
api1:0.412 sec
api2:0.752 sec
db_insert:0.132 sec
```

This is how each Process creates its own consumer, fetches messages and runs the analysis on the code:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(group_id='my-group', 
                         bootstrap_servers='localhost', 
                         value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('ascii'))
consumer.subscribe(topics='usrReq')
while True:
    msg = next(consumer).value['id']
    method(msg)
```

Where could be the problem in this setup?

Comment: hi, what is next(consumer) and what is method(msg)? Why don't you e.g. create one or two consumer processes which will consumer all the messages from the Kafka and put it into internal Python Queue so you can spin multiple Python processes to process data from the Python Queue?

Comment: hi! 
method is the function's name which should process the data coming from the queue. next() is iterator to fetch message from kafka queue.
I don't do that because kafka messages keep coming continuously and even if they stop it's not memory efficient to take messages into a queue first. 
Instead, I utilised Redis job queues, instead of Kafka and it works really fast now.

Comment: Hey, i do move messages from Kafka to internal Python Queue and keep streaming data into Kafka and keep processing moved data in parallel. I use Kafka and Python only.